# Can I read this captcha with imagemagick/tesseract?

Tags: imagemagick, ocr, captcha, tesseract

I'm a week trying to read this captcha. I'm using imagemagick to treat the image and tesseract to interpret.
But without success. Could anyone help me?

Thank you!

[image: captcha-novo.png]
.

```
convert captcha-novo.png -fuzz -50% -transparent black -fuzz 15% -fill black -opaque 'rgb(16,128,176)' -fuzz 40% -fill white +opaque blue -colorspace gray captcha-interpretado.png
```

[image: captcha-novo.png]
.

```
tesseract captcha-interpretado.png page-empty.txt
```

Comment: The point of a captcha is to be hard to read.

Comment: @lucas-ferreira-da-costa Did you solve this issue? Coult you please share an example